# How to upload file with non-ascii file name using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.4.4 and Django 1.10.
This is post request in the client side:

```
$http.post(fileUrl, fd, {
    withCredentials: true,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
}).success(function(data) {
....
```

In the server side I have the following:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    file_ids = []
    file_list = request.FILES.getlist('file_path')
    for file in file_list:
        serializer = FileSerializer(data={'file_path': file})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
....
```

With filname such as foo.pdf the file is uploaded properly. But when filename contains, as example, Armenian letter: ա.pdf, I'm getting the UnicodeEncodeError error:
[UnicodeEncodeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbQmn.png),
[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCtc.png).

Comment: You should post the tracebacks in your question (links to external sites go stale). There is a button in the django error page to get a copy-and-pasteable traceback.  As to your problem, you will need to sanitize filenames before trying to save them to your server's file system.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to embed image directly in my question, so steckoverflow system includes the link instead. Sure, "copy-and-pasteable traceback" is the right way. I will put it into question ASAP. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely means that you didn't set the system languages variables.

Some applications - supervisor for example - that helps run a Django projet do not take the default system into account. You sometime need to set it yourself.

Most likely you'll be missing:

- LANG="C.UTF-8"
- LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
- LC_LANG="C.UTF-8"

for example.

Comment: I'm running Docker and  when I check my configuration in an interactive Python shell I didn't get UTF-8 as noticed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/unicode/#files)
In the mentioned link it is recommended to set expected encoding using the LANG environment variable:
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
I was surprised that it didn't help (I will write here when I find out why it happened). But after setting variables that you specified, sys.getfilesystemencoding() output became UTF-8 and files with non-ascii names uploaded as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad this could help. Took me some time to figure those when this happened to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) file name on your model's save method. You can find how to override model's save method from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).Idea is before you saving your object, change the file name.ınstead of "ա.pdf", slugify probably will change it to "w.pdf". You can also add
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
in the top of your view like [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/_modules/django/utils/encoding/).

Comment: Thanks for the nice tricks. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` didn't help. @Linovia's answer is right. I didn't set the system languages variables.